How to get list of permissions for a role in Postgres?
I'm trying to do what is described here.
That is, execute the following:
BEGIN;
DROP ROLE role_name;
ROLLBACK;

and get the:

list of permissions it can find that are granted to the role.

I can't seem to do this. I see no output and the Messages after executing don't help:

The docs don't give any indication that this actually does what @user:176905 said in the linked answer.

Use a client that shows you the messages.

@LaurenzAlbe I've edited my question with a picture of what I see in the "Messages". Do you get more information in yours?

That looks like there are no messages and DROP ROLE was successful.
That would mean that there are no permissions granted to that role directly.
